# jQuery - How to hide an element and its children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` which I would like to hide along with all of its `children`. I thought that a simple `selector.hide()` would do the trick but it's still there.

HTML

```
<div class="row well">
  <div class="artistAlbumInfo well col-md-6 ">
    <h3><span id="artist"></span> - <span id="track"></span></h3>
    <img src="" id="art" class="albumArt">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3 id="album"></h3>
    <h4>Playstate <p id="playState"></p></h4>
    <h4>Position <p id="position"></p></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.row .well').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/375c8v2a/1/

Any ideas?

Comment: You're doing it wrong, just remove the second class `.well` you only need to point for the first one `$('.row').hide();`. Check out the online example on jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/375c8v2a/2/

Comment: I actually have multiple `rows` and I only want to target the one with both classes.

Comment: If `well` is a class created only for that specific `row` with the purpose of hiding that row, then you can use it as the trigger to hide it like this - `$('.well').hide();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have didn't work because `.row .well` means "an element with class `well` *inside* (as a child or deeper descendant) an element with class `row`. In CSS, the space is the [*descendant combinator*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).

To seelct the element that has *both* classes, remove the space:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.row.well').hide();
  // ----^
});
```

That means "an element with class `row` and class `well`".

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a space between classes if you want to hide only those with both classes

```
$('.row.well').hide();
```

To do either or add a comma

```
$('.row, .well').hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

$('.row').hide();

please remove second class

Comment: This won't work, because I actually have multiple `row` classes. I included the second class, to try to find a more specific selection

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read on the comments the `.well` class was intentionally created to specify which `.row` class will be hiding since you have a lot of `row` classes. Then you can use it as the trigger to hide that `row`, instead of doing: `$('.row.well').hide();` you can just simply specify the targeted class by doing:

```
$('.well').hide();
```

Click here to see a <kbd>[example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/papbmyf2/)</kbd>